# Close menu item when clicking on another menu element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I make other slide-down menus close when clicking on another menu item? Right now all menu items are opening one by one and they can only be closed by clicking on the item again.

Here's a demo: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/33qKz

And here's the code

```js
    function htmlbodyHeightUpdate(){
  var height3 = $( window ).height()
  var height1 = $('.nav').height()+50
  height2 = $('.main').height()
  if(height2 > height3){
   $('html').height(Math.max(height1,height3,height2)+10);
   $('body').height(Math.max(height1,height3,height2)+10);
  }
  else
  {
   $('html').height(Math.max(height1,height3,height2));
   $('body').height(Math.max(height1,height3,height2));
  }
  
 }
 $(document).ready(function () {
  htmlbodyHeightUpdate()
  $( window ).resize(function() {
   htmlbodyHeightUpdate()
  });
  $( window ).scroll(function() {
   height2 = $('.main').height()
     htmlbodyHeightUpdate()
  });
 });
```

```css
/* Adding gvnix styles css - NO COPIAR */

@import 'http://geo-gvnix.rhcloud.com/resources/styles/standard.css';

/* Custom fixed navs */

header.navbar+nav.navbar {
  /* margin-top: 20px;same margin-bottom .navbar */
}
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.sidebar.navbar-fixed-top {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 998px) {
  .navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top {
    margin-top: 100px;
  }
  .sidebar.navbar-fixed-top {
    margin-top: 150px;
  }
}
/* Custom navbar default: global*/

.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #666;
  text-shadow: none;
  min-width: 150px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #666;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #666;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #acc47f;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #acc47f;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
  color: #608224;
  background-color: #acc47f;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .caret {
  border-top-color: #ccc;
  border-bottom-color: #ccc;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .caret:hover {
  border-top-color: #333;
  border-bottom-color: #333;
}
/* Custom sidebar menu */

/*Remove rounded coners*/

nav.sidebar.navbar {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
nav.sidebar,
.main {
  -webkit-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
  transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
}
/* Add gap to nav and right windows.*/

.main {
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}
/* .....NavBar: Icon only with coloring/layout.....*/

/*small/medium side display*/

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /*Allow main to be next to Nav*/
  .main {
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    /*keeps 100% minus nav size*/
    margin-left: 40px;
    float: right;
  }
  /*lets nav bar to be showed on mouseover*/
  nav.sidebar:hover + .main {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
  /*Center Brand*/
  nav.sidebar.navbar.sidebar>.container .navbar-brand,
  .navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  /*Center Brand*/
  nav.sidebar .navbar-brand,
  nav.sidebar .navbar-header {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  /*Center Icons*/
  nav.sidebar a {
    padding-right: 13px;
    min-width: 100px;
  }
  /*custom sidebar nav*/
  nav.sidebar ul.nav.navbar-nav {
    margin: 0;
  }
  nav.sidebar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: white;
  }
  /*adds border top to first nav box */
  nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li:first-child {
    border-top: 1px #e5e5e5 solid;
  }
  /*adds border to bottom nav boxes*/
  nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li {
    border-bottom: 1px #e5e5e5 solid;
  }
  /*adds background on hover*/
  nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #43600E;
  }
  /*removes border last element*/
  nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li.last {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  /* Colors/style dropdown box*/
  nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  /*allows nav box to use 100% width*/
  nav.sidebar .navbar-collapse,
  nav.sidebar .container-fluid {
    padding: 0 0px 0 0px;
  }
  /*colors dropdown box text */
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: #777;
  }
  /*O quanto o menu irá esconder á esquerda*/
  /*gives sidebar width/height*/
  nav.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -270px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 8000;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  /*give sidebar 100% width;*/
  nav.sidebar li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /* Move nav to full on mouse over*/
  nav.sidebar:hover {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  /*for hiden things when navbar hidden*/
  .forAnimate {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
/* .....NavBar: Fully showing nav bar..... */

@media (min-width: 1330px) {
  /*     Allow main to be next to Nav
    .main{
      width: calc(100% - 200px); keeps 100% minus nav size
      margin-left: 200px;
    }

    Show all nav
    nav.sidebar{
      margin-left: 0px;
      float: left;
    }
    Show hidden items on nav
    nav.sidebar .forAnimate{
      opacity: 1;
    } */
}
nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  color: #CCC;
  background-color: transparent;
}
nav:hover .forAnimate {
  opacity: 1;
}
/*---- FIM SLIDE MENU*/

.nav-side-menu {
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 200;
  background-color: #2e353d;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  color: #e1ffff;
}
.nav-side-menu .brand {
  background-color: #23282e;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
  display: none;
}
.nav-side-menu ul,
.nav-side-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*    
    .collapsed{
       .arrow:before{
                 font-family: FontAwesome;
                 content: "\f053";
                 display: inline-block;
                 padding-left:10px;
                 padding-right: 10px;
                 vertical-align: middle;
                 float:right;
            }
     }
*/
}
.nav-side-menu ul :not(collapsed) .arrow:before,
.nav-side-menu li :not(collapsed) .arrow:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f078";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .active,
.nav-side-menu li .active {
  border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
  background-color: #4f5b69;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active {
  color: #d19b3d;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active a,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active a {
  color: #d19b3d;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li {
  background-color: #181c20;
  border: none;
  line-height: 28px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:hover,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #020203;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:before,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f105";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.nav-side-menu li {
  padding-left: 0px;
  border-left: 3px solid #2e353d;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
}
.nav-side-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e1ffff;
}
.nav-side-menu li a i {
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.nav-side-menu li:hover {
  border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
  background-color: #4f5b69;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 10 !important;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .brand {
    text-align: left !important;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    line-height: 50px !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu .menu-list .menu-content {
    display: block;
  }
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--nav sidebar -->
<aside>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse sidebar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <div class="nav-side-menu">
      <div class="brand">Brand Logo</div>
      <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>

      <div class="menu-list">

        <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-lg"></i> Dashboard
            </a>
          </li>

          <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#products" class="collapsed active">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i> UI Elements  <i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg btn pull-right" style="margin-top:5px"></i></a>
          </li>
          <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="products">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">CSS3 Animation</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">General</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Buttons</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Tabs & Accordions</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Typography</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">FontAwesome</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Slider</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Panels</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Widgets</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Bootstrap Model</a>
            </li>
          </ul>


          <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#service" class="collapsed">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe fa-lg"></i> Services <span class="arrow"></span></a>
          </li>
          <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="service">
            <li>New Service 1</li>
            <li>New Service 2</li>
            <li>New Service 3</li>
          </ul>


          <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#new" class="collapsed">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-car fa-lg"></i> New <span class="arrow"></span></a>
          </li>
          <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="new">
            <li>New New 1</li>
            <li>New New 2</li>
            <li>New New 3</li>
          </ul>


          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i> Profile
            </a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i> Users
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</aside>

<div class="main">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML structure is not quite what Bootstrap expects and you won't be able to use the easy way of `data-parent` attribute on this structure (the items should be divs and have the class panel anyway). Please see documentation for more info if interested. But for your problem and something you can make work directly into your HTML. I added `toggle-this` class to all the parent menu items which are toggled and added the attribute `data-parent="menu-content"` to them also. Then I just use this jQuery function to see if there are any menus expanded on click and collapse all the other than the one just clicked like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.toggle-this', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  var $this = $(this);
  var parent = $this.data('parent');
  var actives = $('#' + parent).find('[aria-expanded="true"]');
  if (actives && actives.length) {
    hasData = actives.data('collapse');
    actives.collapse('hide');
  }
  var target = $this.attr('data-target') || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, ''); //strip for ie7
  $(target).collapse('toggle');
});
```

Here's a working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/x5j6v5fq/

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!

Comment: Do you mind giving credit for the answer? Upvote/accept the answer?

Comment: No reputation to accept the answer? :P Just press the checkmark on the left hand-side of this question under the arrows. Well yeah, it doesn't really matter. Just saying, don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 2):

Your html does not follow the documentation from bootstrap.
The right structure should be something like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">UI Elements <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">CSS3 Animation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">General</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Buttons</a></li>
        ...
      </ul>
    </li>
    ...
  </ul>
```

I relize that this would mean you have to re-style some parts of your navigation, but it gives you the functionality that you want. 
For more information check [bootstraps documentation about navbars](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Alternative you can make a little script to change/remove classes on the opened menu items when you click a new one.